# Payum - package for Laravel 4. How do I create Model data using Eloquent instead of FilesystemStorage?

Tags: laravel, paypal, payum

I'm try to save de Payment details in Laravel 4.1 using Eloquent. I have tried to create my models like documentation payum said, but it doesn't work to me. My code:

payum/payum-laravel-package/config.php:

```
<?php

use Payum\Core\Storage\FilesystemStorage;
use Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Api;
use Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\PaymentFactory as PaypalPaymentFactory;

$detailsClass = 'Payum\Core\Model\ArrayObject';
$tokenClass = 'Payum\Core\Model\Token';

$paypalPayment = PaypalPaymentFactory::create(new Api(array(
    'username' => 'MY_USER_NAME',
    'password' => 'MY_PASS',
    'signature' => 'MY_SIGN',
    'sandbox' => true
)));

return array(
    'token_storage' => new FilesystemStorage(__DIR__.'/../../../../storage/payments', $tokenClass, 'hash'),
    'payments' => array(
        'paypal_es' => $paypalPayment,
    ),
    'storages' => array(
        $detailsClass => new FilesystemStorage(__DIR__.'/../../../../storage/payments', $detailsClass),
    )
);
```

controllers/PaypalController.php

```
<?php

use Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Api;

class PaypalController extends BaseController
{
    public function prepareExpressCheckout()
    {

       $paymentName = 'paypal_es';

       $storage = \App::make('payum')->getStorage('Payum\Core\Model\ArrayObject');

         /** @var $paymentDetails PaymentDetails */
           $paymentDetails = $storage->createModel();
           $paymentDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'] = 'EUR';
           $paymentDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = '1.21';
           $paymentDetails['NOSHIPPING'] = Api::NOSHIPPING_NOT_DISPLAY_ADDRESS;
           $paymentDetails['REQCONFIRMSHIPPING'] = Api::REQCONFIRMSHIPPING_NOT_REQUIRED;
           $paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0'] = Api::PAYMENTREQUEST_ITERMCATEGORY_DIGITAL;
           $paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0'] = '1.21';
           $paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0'] = '1';
           $paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0'] = 'Modulo 1';
           $paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0'] = 'Descripción Módulo 1';
           $storage->updateModel($paymentDetails);

            $captureToken = \App::make('payum.security.token_factory')->createCaptureToken($paymentName, $paymentDetails, 'payment_done');

           $paymentDetails['RETURNURL'] = $captureToken->getTargetUrl();
           $paymentDetails['CANCELURL'] = $captureToken->getTargetUrl();
         //  $paymentDetails['INVNUM'] = $paymentDetails->getId();
           $storage->updateModel($paymentDetails);

       return \Redirect::to($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
    }

    /**
     * @return \Payum\Core\Security\GenericTokenFactoryInterface
     */
    protected function getTokenFactory()
    {
        return \App::make('payum.security.token_factory');
    }
}
```

This code work well, but I'd like to use Eloquent instead of FilesystemStorage creating my own models. I've tried following Payum documentation but doesn't work to me:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

use Payum\Core\Model\ArrayObject;

class PaymentDetails extends ArrayObject
{
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

and

```
use Payum\Core\Model\Token;

class PaymentSecurityToken extends Token
{
}
```

How can I do it? Any help will be appreciated because I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You might be interested in taking a look at my [PayPal Glass solution](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-glass) I just started putting together a little while ago.  I'm basically replicating everything the PayPal.com interface gives you, but I'm doing it in Laravel -> Bootstrap with my  own [PHP Class Library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  Anyway, I'm already doing all of my PayPal API stuff within a model, so you can see how that is put together and maybe it'll help you with your setup.

Comment: Your examples show that you use filesystem storage, but you need Eloquent one. Such storage does not provided out of the box, but we have plans to add it in near future.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewAngell for your answer. I've seen you PayPal Glass solution and I hope you can finish your project ASAP because it's a great idea. I'll follow your progress on it.

Comment: Thanks @MaksimKotlyar for your input. I wish there was a solution in Laravel-Payum using Eloquent. I hope Payum team add it in near future because I think it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

[from the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200236/payum-package-for-laravel-4-how-do-i-create-model-data-using-eloquent-instead/28545200#comment39277513_25200236)]

> Your examples show that you use filesystem storage, but you need
>   Eloquent one. Such storage does not provided out of the box, but we
>   have plans to add it in near future.

[Answer]

The storage is here now. Here's how you have to modify the config to work with it:

```
<?php

use Payum\LaravelPackage\Storage\EloquentStorage;
use Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\PaymentFactory;

// it is not same model as you used but you get the idea.
$detailsClass = 'Payum\LaravelPackage\Model\Order';
$tokenClass = 'Payum\LaravelPackage\Model\Token';

$paymentFactory = new PaymentFactory();

return array(
    'token_storage' => new EloquentStorage($tokenClass),
    'payments' => array(
        'paypal' => $paymentFactory->create(array(
            'username' => 'MY_USER_NAME',
            'password' => 'MY_PASS',
            'signature' => 'MY_SIGN',
            'sandbox' => true
        ));,
    ),
    'storages' => array(
        $detailsClass => new EloquentStorage($detailsClass),
    )
);
```

Here's the [documentation](http://payum.org/doc/0.14/PayumLaravelPackage/eloquent_storage).